# Can I use asynchronous programming to fetch data from a server?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

This is my situation:
I have a account (userid/password) to communicate with an airline central reservation system through their API.
The API provide methods to connect, disconnect, sign in, signout, sendcommand and getdatareturn.

This is the steps I do sequentially to get wanted data.

1. Connect to host
2. sign in to system
3. send a command to get a list of passergers of a flight at a specified date from a city to another city (LD command with some parameter like flight no, 
   flight date, pair of city for original and destination),
   but in this step, the host only return a part of the full list (for example, it return only 20 passengers and
   end of this list is a # character to signal that there are more)
   if I want a full list, I must send another command (MD command) to move down and so on to the end of list (with the signal by the END string)
   .The passenger list content passenger name, class and a PRN code, base on these PNR code, I must send another command to get details passenger information 
   like fullname, itinerary, contact information ... then process it (this consume some time to do)(and in this details, I can send various command to get more information...)
4. sign out of system
5. disconnect from host

Can I  use multithread or parallel techonology for #3 to get data from server?

Comment: You might want to clean up #3. Are all that information really necessary for the question? What are you using to invoke all commands? A `HttpWebRequest`? A complete api library provided by your client?

Comment: A complete api library provided by my client

Comment: Don't you think this might depend on the API? You may want to ask your vendor.

Comment: @jgauffin - All the information was required for the correct answer.  While I agree it could be reduced to a few statements, it really serves no purpose, since the author is asking the wrong question.

Comment: @IBC - He likely is already doing the entire operation on its own thread.  He wants to get the list on its own thread(s).  He did not indicate any problems with this operation blocking the main ui thread.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't see a correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the type of connection. How do you connect, and do you remain connected?

If it's a pair of sockets that keep communicating (i.e. stateful), you could try to create another connection, log in again, and request the data you want. If it's done stateless (over HTTP for example) using some kind of session ID to correlate subsequent requests, you could simply simultaneously issue multiple requests with the same session ID and see if that works.

So through your initial connection you request the list of PNR's, and then use that connection and new connections to request passenger data for multiple passengers at the time, getting all data for all passengers on the list.

If both options to achieve that don't work, and you're stuck to using one connection, I'm afraid there is no other solution. Couldn't you try to contact them to ask if this is possible?

Comment: He is trying to get the full list.  He really doesn't actually want to get the list over multiple threads, he just wants the entire list, thats at least how I read his question.

Comment: As I'm saying, he could get the whole list through one connection and then request the full details of each passenger by issuing those requests over multiple connections. He didn't specify what part he wants to speed up. If his processing is the bottleneck, he could start a thread for each received passenger to process and do all data requests over one connection. If it's the requesting data itself that's slow, he could try to issue multiple requests simultaneously over multiple connections.

Comment: I personal view the question as he is simply trying to get the entire list and doesn't understand how to do that.  He doesn't really seem to ask "how do I speed this up" I could be entirely off base here.

Comment: +1 I would also have created a queue with all PNRs and then use one or more threads to fetch the details.

Comment: @Ramhound: Why would he ask about multithreading if he didn't want to speed things up. It sounds awfully slow to query a web service (or whatever it is) several times to get a complete passenger list and then do one query per passenger to get details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can I use multithread or parallel techonology for #2 to get data from server?
```

What purpose would it serve?

You cannot log out of the system until the data is returned, and the last two steps certainly are not resource intensive, or dependent upon your user interface.

What you actually want to do, sending the command more then once, is not really a task for multiple threads.  You simply want to send the command until the symbol that indicates there isn't additional data is not detected.

If you are not already doing this that simply means you should.

This is no different then reading user input within a console application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid my answer is "It depends".  I see no problems with parallel queries from the client side, and some of the information (such as per passenger detail) could probably be done in a separate, parallel query, but getting the full list sounds as if it should be done in a single thread / connection.

Why:  I don't know the system you're querying, but it sounds as if it saves the state of your query (what is he asking for, how far down the list is he currently) and so would probably not handle "Give me parts 1, 2, and 3" of the list very well, especially if part 3 didn't exist (and you don't know until you see the "#" at the end of part 2, which depends on part 1...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could perhaps use parallel operations to allow users to issue more than one query at the same time, assuming that the CRS allows multiple connections from the same IP.  The user might, for example have more than one 'CRS' form on their screen and so be handling more than one query at the same time, eg for different dates, airports, flights, pax.

As noted by other posters, if the users is only processing one query at a time, there is not much point in paralleling anything, (except maybe the UI and client protocol so that the UI is not locked and so allow query cancel).

That said, given a requirement like this, I would normally design in such a way that multiple queries are the default behaviour anyway.  I would have the CRS query form host everything needed to interact with the CRS so that, if necessary/possible, two instances of the form would allow two concurrent queries if supported by the server.  This is more flexible than the alternative of running two processes.